# Calling images dynamicly using javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript

i am new to Javascript and i have created the code below it works fine no problem at all however i want to know what is i want to pull the image dynamically using php and javascript from mysql database how can i refactor my code bellow. thanks in advance for your contribution.

```
var myimage = document.getelementById("mainImage");
var imageArray =["images/overlook.jpg","images/garden.jpg","images/park.jpg"];

var imageIndex =0;

function changeimage(){
      myimage.setAttribute("src",imageArray[imageIndex]);
      imageIndex++;
      if(imageIndex >= imageArray.length){
      imageIndex = 0;
}

setInterval(changeimage, 5000);
```

Comment: Are you storing the images as blobs in the database?

Comment: am just storing them as usual as a varchar url address. and what is What is blobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of several options.

1. Query the database for the column with the URL of the images.

   ```
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT url FROM images");
   ```
2. Then something like this to get an array out of it:

   ```
   $images = array();
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
       $images[] = $row['url'];
   }
   ```
3. Then generate this string (that you use in the Javascript provided):

   ```
   var imageArray = ["images/overlook.jpg","images/garden.jpg","images/park.
   ```

   using the array you retrieved from the database. You could use `json_encode` in PHP for this if you don't want to mess around with error prone string building.

   ```
   $imagesAsJsonArray = json_encode($images);
   ```
4. Echo it. Done.

Not the most elegant of solutions. But it gives you something to play with. Check out a few PHP tutorials online and you'll soon get the hang of it.

Comment: Your the man thanks alot for your time that gives me a very good idea, but onemore thing do i put<script> tag within the php code to assign the array from php to the array of Javascript

Comment: Yes. You could do it like that. `<script type="text/html">var imageArray = <?php echo json_encode($imageArray); ?>;</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Two choices:

1. Using PHP when your page is created, put an array of images in the page and use page-level javascript to cycle among them.
2. Using Ajax in the page, call from the page to the server to get the next image and then use client-side javascript to make that returned image visible on the page.

Comment: can you show me an example if you do not mind to get a better fell of what your saying

Comment: @SalimAlmughairi - That sounds like a pretty basic question.  Since I don't know what toolset you're using on the client, I'd suggest you read up on ajax which is how a client makes a call to the server while staying on the same web page.  Then, after you familiarize yourself a bit with the technology, you can ask a more specific question.  There are hundreds of thousands of articles on the web about ajax.

Comment: thank you but it sound basic because i am still new to javascript.